# SON 28 Hub Dynamo "Rotation Lock"?

Tags: wheels, dynamo

I have bought and successfully installed a SON 28 Dynamo Hub and a Supernova The Plug III on my bicycle.

However, when the wheel spins, the Hub Dynamo connectors will spin together with the wheel.

Is there a specific way to install the wheel packing the SON 28 so that the Hub's electric connectors will remain in place as the wheel spins?

Comment: Quick question: did you left the cable on the right side of the fork, as per instructions: http://www.nabendynamo.de/produkte/pdf/english/Montage_SON_28_klassik_e.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Start by checking that the axle is clamped firmly in place. The connectors are part of the axle assembly and shouldn't be able to turn with the hub unless the axle is loose.

Note that the comment above about having the connections on the right hand side of the hub applies to older versions of the SON28. The newest versions (the 2015 40/48-hole tandem hubs as well as the 2012 and later versions with the smaller flange permit the connections to be on either side, http://www.nabendynamo.de/produkte/pdf/english/son282013e.pdf).

Comment: There is a bit of resistance due to the magnets, if you are holding the clamp/quick release  by and and spinning the hub/wheel the axle will likely spin on the clamp/quick release due to this resistance.  Once in the fork the axle will be held firmly in place and the hub will spin on the bearings.  This resistance is less once the hub starts spinning faster and is only about 1 watt (small compared to wind and tire drag).